# How to create required file name in unix using shell script

Tags: file, shell, unix

I am reading one property file which contains some file paths using shell script. Now depending on this file path I want to create name of zip file. Something like this...My property file contents::

```
path=tmp/inputs/logs/abc
path=tmp/backup/inte/xyz
destpath=abc/xyz
```

Now I am able to create file name as abc.zip and xyz.zip as:

```
paths=`grep path myfile.property |cut -d= -f2`
d_path=`grep destpath myfile.property |cut -d= -f2`     
filename=$d_path/$(basename $paths).zip
```

Which create abc.zip and xyz.zip. But I want to create name by taking last three parameter of the path. Something like this...

- for `abc.zip` it should be `inputs_logs_abc.zip` and
- for `xyz.zip` it should be `backup_inte_xyz.zip`

**EDIT**

```
Paths=`grep path myfile.txt |cut -d= -f2`

d_Path=`grep destpath myfile.txt |cut -d= -f2`

for s_Path in $Paths

   do

       prefix=${Paths%%/*/*/*}    
       without_prefix=${Paths##${prefix}/}
       slashes_to_underscores=${without_prefix//\//_}
       zipFile=$d_Path/${slashes_to_underscores}.zip
       find $s_Path -type f -name "*.log" | xargs zip -mT $zipFile -@

   done
```

Above is my code.By using this i am not able to achieve my target.
Can somebody help me in this?

Comment: Which shell are you scripting? What is the relevance of `destpath` and `d_path` in these snippets?

Comment: I am using bash.destpath is keyword which present in property file, according to which i read this file and store this path in d_path variable.

Comment: Then my answer should solve your problem. You can try it out at a prompt and echo the variables as you go to see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `bash` (this would also apply to `zsh` or similar), you could use its in-built parameter substitution.

```
% path=tmp/inputs/logs/abc
% prefix=${path%%/*/*/*}
% without_prefix=${path##${prefix}/}
% slashes_to_underscores=${without_prefix//\//_} 
% filename=${slashes_to_underscores}.zip        
% echo $filename           
inputs_logs_abc.zip
```

You can prepend `${d_path}` as appropriate to `${filename}`. `$path` in my example is hard-coded, you will assign this in a loop over `${paths}`, as per [fahd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753918/how-to-move-files-from-one-path-to-another-path-in-unix-using-shell-script/3759295#3759295) to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753918/how-to-move-files-from-one-path-to-another-path-in-unix-using-shell-script).

- `${var//exp/sub}` replaces all instances of `exp` in `$var` with `sub`
- `${var%%exp}` trims any instance of `exp` from the right of `var`
- `${var##exp}` trims any instance of `exp` from the left of `var`

**Edit (following some sleep and clarification):**

`prefix=${path%%/*/*/*}` does a *greedy* match from right-to-left. If you have a '/' before tmp this will break (this is not what you said you were doing in your comment, but would give that result). Change this line to be `prefix=${path%/*/*/*}` (single percentage sign: non-greedy) and this should fix longer and shorter paths.

**Edit 2 (following update to question):**

I can see three problems:

1. "Paths=`grep path myfile.txt |cut -d= -f2`" # This matches "destpath=abc/xyz", you should probably `grep` for `'^path='` to get just lines that start with "path=".
2. You are using `${Paths}` twice inside the loop where you should use (the curiously-named) `${s_Path}`.
3. You are still using the greedy match in the `prefix=` line. See my previous edit.

Comment: @Johnsyweb,thanx for your reply. But above code cretae file name with full path,means if path is path=tmp/xyz/inputs/logs/abc then it is creating file name as tmp_xyz_inputs_logs_abc.zip. But i want only last three directories name as inputs_logs_abc.zip.

Comment: I use your code in loop(fahd's answer) which is present in my previous question.

Comment: The code in my example was copied directly from the command-line. `path=tmp/inputs/logs/abc` is the input and `inputs_logs_abc.zip` is the output as demonstrated. Please append the full code that you now have as an edit to your question so that I can see where the bug is.

Comment: I have pasted my code as EDIT in question.Can you please check why it is not working with me.My requirement of above code hope you know from my previous question which you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly. I won't write your code for you, though. That is not what this site is for!

Comment: Actually i was pasted my code in EDIT by making some changes. So the problem no 2 u mentioned is typo. About problem number 1 and 3, i have make changes as for now i use grep for ^path, and for greedy match i use prefix=${path%/*/*/*/}(adding one single slash at end). for this i have done changes in my myfile.txt also as path=tmp/inputs/logs/abc/(Here also i add one slash at end). So its working fine for me.Thanks for your help!!!Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
paths=$(grep path myfile.property |cut -d= -f2)
d_path=$(grep destpath myfile.property |cut -d= -f2)
extname=$(echo $paths | sed 's%^.*/\([^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*\)$%\1%;s%/%_%g')
filename=$d_path/$extname.zip
```

The first substitute in the `sed` script now removes everything before the last three components of the path - not removing anything if there are only two - and the second maps the remaining slashes to underscores.  Note that you will have problems if the paths have trailing slashes (though you can add a substitute to remove them).  You'd also get a leading underscore in the name if it contained, say, `/tmp/pattern`.  You might need to worry about using '`[^/][^/]*`' in place of just '`[^/]*`' to ensure that there aren't empty component names (and then you might worry about doubled slashes too).  And GNU Sed provides you with extra regex features so you might be able to use '`[^/]+`' instead.

Comment: Thanx for reply..but the path which i given here all are just examples..so we cannot predict any keyword in path.However path and d_path keywords in property file are final.